# How to sort filter attributes in magento based on product count

Tags: magento

I have a problem with magento filters. I need to sort the filter attributes based on count of products associated to that filter attribute. I need this sort order for filter attributes.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the template for generating the filters is at: template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml. The filter attributes are in a regular PHP array, which you can sort with [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php). You can even include a custom sorting function directly in uasort. The first step is to rewrite the beginning so it looks something like this.

```
<?php 
$items = $this->getItems();
uasort($items, function($a,$b) {
    return ($a->getCount() - $b->getCount())* -1;
    });
?>
<?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
<? /* comment out the original and use the new sorted array
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
*/ ?>
```

But this will also sort price filter tiers from most to least products, which you probably(?) don't want. You would just have to check what kind of filter it is or what the name of the filter is. But this is basically how you would do it.

Comment: i got the error when i used the above uasort function,
"Fatal error: Base lambda function for closure not found in".
Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Did it work for a little bit and then start showing the error? It might be this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52144